# iPhone - how can I insert a mathematical function through a textfield? 

Tags: iphone

I want to make an iphone program that makes the graph of a mathematic function, like `sin(x)`.
So, I want to put the mathematical expression `sin(x)` in a UITextfield and then take it and use it like a function.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. You need to evaluate an `NSString` as if it were a mathematical equation and obtain a number from it.
2. You need to plot some numbers on a graph.

Fortunately, there are projects out there to help you with this:

1. [DDMathParser](http://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser) - a library I wrote for evaluating strings as mathematical expressions.  There are other alternatives, such as [ANExpressionParser](https://github.com/unixpickle/ANExpressionParser) and [GCMathParser](http://apptree.net/parser.htm), but ANEP doesn't always parse things correctly (ex: -2 ** -2 should be -0.25, and it parses it as 0.25) and GCMathParser isn't extensible and is no longer under development.  However, GCMathParser is *insanely fast*.  It is much faster than `DDMathParser` (by a couple orders of magnitude), but DDMathParser will still parse things in a fraction of a second.
2. [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) - A pretty awesome graphing framework.   I haven't had occasion to use it myself, but it's also under active development and has a pretty solid community of users.  I've heard nothing but good things about it.

Answer (score -1):

You could convert the text expression into Javascript ("sin" -> "Math.sin", etc.), run the Javascript code inside a UIWebView, get a string result back, and convert it into numeric data.

Comment: And it's also a solution that's built-in to iOS, and with the parser built into webkit, and thus supported by Apple.  The current webkit JS engine is also no slouch performance-wise.

Comment: fair enough, but you'd have to manipulate the string to get it to be valid JavaScript, and keep a uiwebview hanging around but not on screen. A uiwebview is not a lightweight object. It can consume significant resources.

Answer (score -1):

A UILabel with text "sin(" followed by UITextFied (with placeholder text) where user enters the value of x, followed by another UILabel with closing brace ")".